# Aggregate query takes too long

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework, nosql

I've made a query using the aggregation framework in the latest version of MongoDB. The problem is that I can't find the way to get the result because it takes too long and the process crashes.

### Collections

**Constructora** with 50.000 documents (including embedded documents and so on)

```
{
    _id: 1,
    edificio: [
        {
            _id:58,
            pais: "Argentina",
            provincia: "Buenos Aires",
            ciudad: "Tandil",
            direccion: "9 de Julio 845",
            departamento: [
                {
                    _id:45648651867,
                    nombre_depto: "a"
                },   
                ...
            ]
        }
        ...
    ]
},
{
    _id:2,
    edificio: [...],
    ...
}
...
```

**variable** with 400.000 documents, including embedded documents.

```
{
    _id:1
    medicion_departamento: [
        {
            _id:1,
            valmax:40
            id_departamento:6,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
},
{
    _id: 2,
    medicion_departamento: [...]
},
...
```

**Medicion** with 8.000.000 documents.

```
{
    _id:1,
    id_departamento: 6,
    id_variable: 1,
    valor: 6269
},
{
    _id:2,
    ...
},
...
```

## Query

I want to get the the adress of the departments (`pais, provincia, ciudad, departamento.nombre`) that exceeds the `valmax` value in "variable" fives time in the field `valor` in "medicion". My query is:

```
db.constructora.aggregate([
        {$unwind:"$edificio"},
        {$unwind:"$edificio.departamento"},
        {$lookup: 
        {
            from: "variable",
            localField: "edificio.departamento._id",
            foreignField: "medicion_departamento.id_departamento",
            as: "var"
        }
        },
        {$unwind: "$var"},
        {$unwind: "$var.medicion_departamento"},
        {$match: {"var.nombre":"electricidad"}},
        {$lookup: 
            {
                from: "medicion",
                localField: "var.medicion_departamento.id_departamento",
                foreignField: "id_departamento",
                as: "med"
            }
        },
        {$unwind:"$med"},
        {$project:{"id_dto":"med.id_departamento", "consumo":"$med.valor","valorMult":{$multiply:["$var.valmax",5]}, "edificio.pais":1, "edificio.provincia":1, "edificio.direccion":1, "edificio.departamento.nombre_depto":1}},
        {$match:{"consumo":{$gt:"valorMult"}}},
        {$group:{_id:{"a": "edificio.pais", "b":"edificio.provincia", "c":"edificio.direccion", "d":"edificio.departamento.nombre_depto"}}}
]);
```

When I remove the last match and group in the pipeline, the query returns the data in 0.08s, but when I run this with match and group it runs until the process crashes. What can I do to fix (or optimize) it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your structure is not helping you here and I have commented before that using `$lookup` where the target `"foreignField"` is actually within an array will actually return "the whole document' and not just the array members. You don't seem to be making any effort to "reduce" such information to just the matching array members, which would be the logical point of the `$lookup`. You should be trying to do that, as there is actually "optimization" done when a `$lookup` is followed by `$unwind` and then `$match`, in that in fact **all three stages** are sent as **one**.

Comment: Also `{$match:{"consumo":{$gt:"valorMult"}}}` does not do what "you think" it does. You are trying to "compare fields", but this is not what `$match` does. Instead you want `$redact`. And indeed you should not `$project` at all. As for the "time taken", the `0.08s` you see is **just the selection of the cursor** and the retrieval of the first 25 documents. With the various `$lookup` and `$unwind` stages you have **significantly** more documents than the original source awaiting processing. That is going to take some time to process. Overall, it looks like the data needs restructuring.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have to do it with this structure, I can't change the schema at all. This is because I'm not the owner

Comment: @NeilLunn If I separate into two different collections "variable" and its embedded arrays (medicion_departamento), do you think that I can take better time?

Comment: There should be "somewhat" of an improvement yes. But what I am basically saying here to to consider the very first "join" for instance. Aside from the initial `$unwind` statements ( which are certainly costly ) the "joined" data resides inside an array. This means that it is **not** the "matching array element" that is returned, but instead the "whole" `"variable"` document which contains any of the array elements that match. As a **first step** you "should" be removing any **non matching** array elements.

Comment: It is difficult to explain without writing out in the form of an "answer". However such an "answer" does not really necessarily *"make you query suddenly more performant"*. Nor does the data presented in the question at present lend itself to a "reproducible" result. As in you do not show sufficient data to even return a "single" aggregated result from the data supplied. So it's a bit unclear what to actually show you how to do it. Perhaps you could amend to show a set of "related" data that can actually obtain a result. But I cannot guarantee stellar performance on the real data set.